# [ask]asp.net mvc update database error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two model classes in one-to-one relationship:

```
class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int DetailPersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DetailPerson DetailPerson { get; set; }
}

class DetailPerson
{
    public int DetailPersonID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and the code for the edit page view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PersonID)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DetailPerson.Address)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DetailPerson.Address)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DetailPerson.PhoneNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DetailPerson.PhoneNumber)

    <input type="submit" value="Edit">

}
```

The EF scaffold uses this code to update data:

```
db.Entry(person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
db.saveChanges();
```

When I submit the edit form, I got an error like this:

**A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary key value does not exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = FK_dbo.People_dbo.DetailPersons_DetailPersonID ]**

But if I do this:

```
Person p = db.Persons.Find(person.PersonID);
p.DetailPerson = person.DetailPerson;
p.FirstName = person.FirstName;
p.LastName = person.LastName;
db.saveChanges();
```

update data success without error

I want to know why the first way causse an error,
when I set the breakpoint at the line containing **EntityState.Modified**,
but the foreign key value ( DetailPersonID ) is 0.
Then, I added @**Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DetailPersonID)** on the edit form.

I got another error:

**A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.**

I still update database on the other way,
I am just curious why the first way which is EF standart to update data got an error.

Comment: **UPDATE**
i add more hidden values on edit form like this and update success
'@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DetailPerson.DetailPersonID) 
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DetailPersonID)'

should i use this way for best practice?

Comment: Yes. This is the expected way to do it. Without the Id, EntityFramework doesn't know which one to update. So it thinks you are trying to add a new Object to the database, rather than update a preexisting object.

Comment: Well one thing I spot there is that you are supposed to mark navigation properties with virtual as in public virtual DetailPerson DetailPerson { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use two classes if there is a one-to-one relationship since EF will normalize the db into the corresponding form anyway. Combine your classes like this.

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

if you must have separate classes (not recommended), do it like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int DetailPersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual DetailPerson DetailPerson { get; set; }
}

public class DetailPerson
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public int DetailPersonID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you retrieve your object, do it like this:

```
// include the detail when retrieving the parent
Person person = db.People.Include(p=>p.DetailPerson).Single(p=>p.PersonId == whateverIdYou Need);

// modify whatever you like
person.DetailPerson.Address = "my new address";

// then your previous statement will work
db.Entry(person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
db.saveChanges();
```